# Error FastDateFormat dont work on tomcat 8

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, tomcat8, apache-commons-lang3

I'm using the FastDateFormat for replacing dateFormat because he is threadSafe,
the clean install is successful with Maven version 3.3.9, the deployment is working with tomcat 7,

My problem is that the deployement don't work when i use tomcat 8.0.x or 8.5.x.

The source Code :

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.google.common.collect.Maps;
import com.leyton.core.shared.GlobalParameters;

@Component
public class HolidayCalendar {
private final Map<LocalDate, String> holidays;

@Autowired
public HolidayCalendar(@Value("${holidayDates}") String[] holidays) throws ParseException {
    FastDateFormat formatter = FastDateFormat.getInstance(GlobalParameters.DATE_FORMAT);
    this.holidays = Maps.newHashMap();

    for (String entry : holidays) {
        String date = entry.split("-")[0];
        String label = entry.split("-")[1];
        this.holidays.put(LocalDate.from(formatter.parse(date).toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())), label);
    }
}

public Map<LocalDate, String> getHolidays() {
    return holidays;
}

public String getHoliday(LocalDate date) {
    return holidays.get(date);
}
}
```

the error i have is :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'holidayCalendar' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/alami/Home/apache-tomcat-8.0.29/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/core-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/leyton/core/server/util/HolidayCalendar.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.leyton.core.server.util.HolidayCalendar]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat.parse(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/Date;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:279) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5236) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1675) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.29]
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_111]
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_111]
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:463) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:413) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.29]
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_111]
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_111]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468) [na:1.8.0_111]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76) [na:1.8.0_111]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309) [na:1.8.0_111]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401) [na:1.8.0_111]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829) [na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324) [na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) [na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) [na:1.8.0_111]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) [na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568) [na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826) [na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683) [na:1.8.0_111]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682) [na:1.8.0_111]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.leyton.core.server.util.HolidayCalendar]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat.parse(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/Date;
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:271) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
... 59 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat.parse(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/Date;
at com.leyton.core.server.util.HolidayCalendar.<init>(HolidayCalendar.java:38) ~[core-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
... 61 common frames omitted
```

It's very important for me to use an dateFormat ThreadSafe in tomcat 8.

Is there any solution for this error, is it a bug on tomcat 8 ? 
There is any other substitute to org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat working on tomcat 8 ?

Thanks in advance for your Help!

Comment: Were you got any solution for this ?